# Import downloaded vdi image in Virtualbox using CLI

Tags: virtualbox

I want to run Debian inside virtualbox on a Debian host without a graphical interface.

I've downloaded a .vdi file. How can I import such a file?

I already tried

```
vboxmanage import Debian\ 9.7\ \(32bit\).vdi --dry-run
```

But that returns

```
VBoxManage: error: Appliance file must have .ovf or .ova extension
```

As vdi is a disk image, not a virtualbox image.

Sam